# Cant add button to already created FlexLayout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Tis is the xml file**

```
<ContentPage Title="Teras">
<ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
        <FlexLayout x:Name="teras">
        <Label Text="Teras"/>
        </FlexLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

see i already have FlexLayout
i want to add button with code but i cant  include the button to this layout :/ im new on xamarin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var button = new Button { .. };
teras.Children.Add(button);
```

Comment: i swear i did that in the begginning but didnt work but now its working :O